# python генератор многоугольников/полигонов (островов)

Tags: python, математика, геометрия

Цель: Мне нужна функция/алгоритм, который возвращает полигон в виде списка точек [[x0,y0],[x1,y1],..]. Полигон не простой. Я создаю генератор карты океана. Полигоны должным быть похожи на острова.

1. Не имеющие строгих геометрических форм (круг/квадрат и т п)
2. Должны иметь в основном ровный берег.
3. Нужны заливы, выступы и т п
4. У островов не должно быть очень резких выступов.

В последствии на таких островах будут располагаться строения (дома, порта и т п)

Острова должны быть как бы разных классов:

- маленькие(мели, простые формы)
- чуть больше(необитаемые, простые формы)
- крупные(заселённые, имеют залив, имеют усложнённую форму)
- большие (несколько заливов, сложная форма острова)

Острова могут образовывать архипелаги.

Я поэкспериментировал:

```
import math, random
random.seed(0)
def generatePolygon( ctrX, ctrY, aveRadius, irregularity, spikeyness, numVerts ) : #Нашёл в интернете.
    '''Start with the centre of the polygon at ctrX, ctrY, 
    then creates the polygon by sampling points on a circle around the centre. 
    Randon noise is added by varying the angular spacing between sequential points,
    and by varying the radial distance of each point from the centre.

    Params:
    ctrX, ctrY - coordinates of the "centre" of the polygon
    aveRadius - in px, the average radius of this polygon, this roughly controls how large the polygon is, really only useful for order of magnitude.
    irregularity - [0,1] indicating how much variance there is in the angular spacing of vertices. [0,1] will map to [0, 2pi/numberOfVerts]
    spikeyness - [0,1] indicating how much variance there is in each vertex from the circle of radius aveRadius. [0,1] will map to [0, aveRadius]
    numVerts - self-explanatory

    Returns a list of vertices, in CCW order.
    ''' 
    irregularity = clip( irregularity, 0,1 ) * 2*math.pi / numVerts
    spikeyness = clip( spikeyness, 0,1 ) * aveRadius
    angleSteps = []
    lower = (2*math.pi / numVerts) - irregularity
    upper = (2*math.pi / numVerts) + irregularity
    sum = 0
    for i in range(numVerts) :
        tmp = random.uniform(lower, upper)
        angleSteps.append( tmp )
        sum = sum + tmp
    k = sum / (2*math.pi)
    for i in range(numVerts) :
        angleSteps[i] = angleSteps[i] / k
    points = []
    angle = random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
    for i in range(numVerts) :
        r_i = clip( random.gauss(aveRadius, spikeyness), 0, 2*aveRadius )
        x = ctrX + r_i*math.cos(angle)
        y = ctrY + r_i*math.sin(angle)
        points.append( (int(x),int(y)) )
        angle = angle + angleSteps[i]
    return points

def clip(x, min, max) :
     if( min > max ) :  return x
     elif( x < min ) :  return min
     elif( x > max ) :  return max
     else :             return x

def smoothPolygon(p,pix): # "обтачивание" полигона по Безье (вроде как).
#Меняет точку исходного полигона на среднюю точку между средними точками отрезков исходящей от соответствующей точки исходного полигона.
    points = []
    for _ in range(0,len(p)):
        a0 = p[_][0]+((((p[(len(p)+_-1)%len(p)][0]+p[_][0])/2+( p[(_+1)%len(p)][0]+p[_][0])/2)/2)-p[_][0])*pix
        a1 = p[_][1]+((((p[(len(p)+_-1)%len(p)][1]+p[_][1])/2+( p[(_+1)%len(p)][1]+p[_][1])/2)/2)-p[_][1])*pix
        points.append([a0,a1])
    return points

def generatePolygon0(p,pix) : # добавляет случайные точку между точками исходного полигона.
    points = []
    for _ in range(0, len(p)):
        points.append(p[_])
        points.append([(p[_][0]+p[int((_+1)%len(p))][0])/2+random.random()*pix*2*(p[_][0]+p[int((_+1)%len(p))][0])/2-(p[_][0]+p[int((_+1)%len(p))][0])/2*pix,(p[_][1]+p[int((_+1)%len(p))][1])/2+random.random()*pix*2*(p[_][1]+p[int((_+1)%len(p))][1])/2-(p[_][0]+p[int((_+1)%len(p))][1])/2*pix])
    return points

if __name__ == '__main__':
    verts = generatePolygon(500, 500, 100, 0.75, 0.5, 20)
    verts = generatePolygon2(verts, 0.05)
    for _ in range(0,3):
        verts = smoothPolygon(verts,2)
    for _ in range(0, 1):
        verts = smoothPolygon(verts, 1)
    # print(verts)
    import pygame
    import sys
    FPS = 60
    pygame.init()
    Form = pygame.display.set_mode((1500, 1000))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.draw.polygon(Form,(255,0,255),verts)
        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()
```

и получил :
[image: -]

Есть ли какие-то другие способы получить нечто лучшее?
Помогите хоть чем ни будь ...

Comment: https://github.com/OlavStornes/pymapgen   https://github.com/wadefletch/terrain  https://github.com/PabloVD/MapGenerator/tree/master  Ну и вообще - https://www.google.com/search?q=python+generate+islands

Comment: В каком формате вам нужен остров: береговая линия? карта высот? что-то ещё?